# INSERT no mysql em outro domínio

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Fazer um INSERT no mysql em outro domínio. Por exemplo: no meu site tem o administrador de site, e lá eu posso cadastrar meus produtos, ao cadastrar, irá cadastrar no meu site e em outro site fora do meu domínio.

Tem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Pra fazer isso o servidor onde está o outro banco de dados tem que permitir acesso externo, então é só você abrir uma nova conexão com as credenciais do banco que você quer realizar o INSERT.

Comment: E é fácil fazer essa permissão de acesso externo?

Comment: Seu servidor tem o cPanel? Se tiver, lá tem uma opção `MySQL Remoto`, daí é só adicionar permissão ao IP do outro site/servidor ou então adicionar `%`, que ele permite acesso a qualquer IP.

Comment: Sim, tem o cPanel